# How to take control to next cell in the same row in a GRID in C#.net

Tags: c#

I have one datagrid in c#.net windows application , I want to type numbers into the cell and want to shift to next cell in the same row after pressing enter , moreover if the cell is last in the row , the control should go to the next row , first column

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

i use this (use for DG form class):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter && this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellInEditMode && this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count-1)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot , its working with my logic , could u plz email me ur email id ...my id is er.arun.agarwal@gmail.com